# RegEx with notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

```
100. 
101. 
102.
```

guys this is my text and i want to change like this:

```
<tag>100.</tag>   
<tag>101.</tag>   
<tag>102.</tag>
```

My RegEx is:

```
[0-9][0-9][0-9]\.
```

Replace with:

```
<tag>\1</tag>
```

But it does not work :( 
I could not see the numbers and dot sign.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need some (capturing) parentheses;

Re:  `(\d{3}\.)`
Replace `<tag>\1</tag>`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `\.` in your brackets. Try this `$regex = ":[\d\.]+:"`.

Comment: Downvote didn't come from me, but I'll postulate. You make a useful point, but it is not the answer to the question. While it's true the asker should escape the `.` to make it literal, that doesn't solve his problem, as a wildcard `.` would still match a period, and there still does not exist a first subpattern to replace `\1`. As an aside, your suggestion places the period within a character class `[ ]` -- periods lose their special meaning in there, so escaping it is actually not necessary in this case.

Comment: I've now retracted my downvote out of courtesy - no malice intended. But to explain it: What are the colons for? Don't think these are needed in Notepad++. The OP was asking about find and replace in Notepad++ but this seems more like PHP? And the OP's regex is looking for 3 digits followed by a dot but this is looking for any number of digits or dots (e.g. 1.2.312.412.1231.23) - not sure if that's what's required?